# PHP preg_match misfunctioning

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this block of code

```
public function onlyLetters($string) {
    if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $string)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it always returns false, what would the reason be?

Comment: Try `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` - you are looking only for a single character and you are not checking that the string contains only letters because you forgot to specify beginning and end markers.

Comment: Show an example of where it returns false when it should return true.

Comment: no, I want to see if the string contains only letters, to check like firstname, lastname etc...

Comment: @Grigor Names can legitimately contain punctuation and characters that do not fall into the `[a-zA-Z]` class, e.g. [Sinéad O'Connor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin%C3%A9ad_O'Connor)

Comment: But how would that be checked against sql injection? Because with ', damage can be done

Comment: Nothing wrong with ' in a name, just ask Tim O'Reilly :)

Comment: @Grigor which is why you always use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or at the very least [escape your input](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @Grigor Well [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) are always a good start... but really that depends on exactly what you're doing with the data and where you will be using it.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'd never heard about prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string most likely doesn't contain what you expect, and doesn't have a single upper or lower case a-z letter.

OR - you aren't handling the return value correctly

If you check these assumptions, you'll probably solve it yourself :)